# Eclipse won't generate import statements, stopped showing Quick Fix suggestions

Tags: java, eclipse

My Eclipse installation suddenly stopped showing import suggestions.  If I type a class name that isn't in the current package, autocomplete works fine and shows the class, but after picking from the drop-down, the class name is highlighted as an error with the message "MyClass cannot be resolved to a variable".  This error shows no Quick Fix suggestions.  However, if I manually add the relevant `import` statement at the top of the file, the code compiles and runs fine.

I've checked my build path and everything appears to be in order -- and like I said, the code runs when I hand-jam the `import` statement -- but losing automatic importing is really slowing me down.  Any idea what could have gone wrong?  It worked fine last week!

ETA: Another note, if it helps: F3 still opens the class declaration, so Eclipse clearly knows what I "mean", even without the import statement.

Also also: Things that have not helped:

- Clean all projects
- Restarting Eclipse
- Restart computer
- Delete `.metadata` from workspace, re-import project
- Start new Java project, re-link source folder, re-add dependencies (not using Maven, but that's not my choice)

Comment: Are you using Maven ?

Comment: No.  This is a course for my daughter, and they distribute a pre-configured Eclipse workspace.  It worked at first, but stopped auto-suggesting at some point.  It's pretty important since she's just learning to code and the automatic imports are part of how they teach the class.

Comment: It's maybe because the jar aren't at the right location. Check the Build Path

Comment: Sorry, I just read again your question, you did it ^^

Comment: Build path is fine -- like I said, it *runs*, it just won't do Quick Fix or add import statements on autocomplete / paste.  It's so bad that core Java classes like `java.util.Map` won't auto-import either.

Comment: Just to be clear, when you code and you do `Ctrl+Space` it doesn't show anything? There are multiples categories of propositions. I don't why but maybe it doesn't show the "Java Subwords Proposal" by default

Comment: No, autocomplete (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>) works fine.  Normally, when you pick a new class from that menu, it will insert the necessary `import` statement for you.  That isn't happening, which is the baffling part :-/

Comment: similar question, nothing here as worked and it hasn't gotten any attention: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538162/eclipse-wont-show-lwjgl-imports-in-quick-fix-menu

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for all the help, everybody, but this turns out to have been a case of a broken Eclipse install.

I still haven't figured out exactly how or what was broken, but I tried to make a new project with a single "Hello World" class.  The New Class wizard errored out with "Creation of element failed" in the class `org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.dom.rewrite.ImportRewriteAnalyzer`.  Once I hit "internal errors" in Eclipse, I gave up and installed a fresh Eclipse from a new download.

With a new Eclipse, I got my Quick Fix suggestions back, as well as automatic imports.  I guess in future I'll try reinstalling Eclipse before I go looking for solutions to obscure errors like this :-/

Answer (score 2):

These kind of situations can occur if your workspace went into a bad state or eclipse was unable to properly save state during last exit of workspace.

Try `Project > Clean` and clean all projects and rebuild all. See if this helps.

Comment: Tried it, no change.  Thanks for the idea, though!

Comment: worked for me.  i had imported a springBoot project.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Clean all your projects. Then update Eclipse.  Then restart of Eclipse. Then restart your development PC.

This happens to me sometimes too, I follow these steps and the problem always goes away.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the other answers works, one brute force suggestion which sometimes resolves weird issues like this would be:

1. Close your Eclipse
2. Delete the `.metadata` folder inside your `Workspace` folder
3. Restart Eclipse

**Note:** This way you're going to lose all your workspace configuration. I advise you to backup it first in case it doesn't works.