# Why won't eclipse show lwjgl imports in the "quick fix" menu?

Tags: java, eclipse, import, ide, lwjgl

*[I have tried everything mentioned in this question with no success.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21236398/eclipse-wont-generate-import-statements-stopped-showing-quick-fix-suggestions#)*

I have also tried deleting the entire workspace and letting eclipse generate a new one, and setting access restrictions.

Deleting my installation of eclipse manually and deleting the eclipse folder in my user folder (windows 10), then reinstalling a fresh download of eclipse didn't work.

eclipse will clean imports just fine. i could import something general, like an entire class, and eclipse will make more specific imports by shortcut or when i save and quit.

*The problem is the quick fix menu on mouseover*, which does not offer any import suggestions. (it will for java classes such as random from java.util though)

Comment: try importing something statically and try again. Something like: import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.*; now try typing glfw and hit [CTRL]+[SPACE]

Comment: @Dynamitos more of a workaround than a solution, but i suppose it's better than going completely "blind". Still doesn't help with import suggestions though.

Comment: its not a "bug" that static functions are not displayed. imagine if you had EVERY avaliable method from the JDK in your suggestions. it would take ages to find something

Comment: @Dynamitos I'm more worried about the import suggestions.

Comment: so just to make this clear: is the problem exclusive to LWJGL or generally libraries?

Comment: @Dynamitos I've just tried it with the Slick2D library, and Import Suggestions work fine. So it seems to be LWJGL specific.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your missconception of the LWJGL library, or Java itself.
Other than C++, in Java functions and variables HAVE to be in the scope of a class. This also includes static functions from OpenGL/LWJGL. Due to that restriction, LWJGL was implemented version-based. That means, all static variables and methods are contained in classes representing the version number the feature was implemented.

For example: glGetVertexArrays was introduced in OpenGL 3.0, which means, that you can find it in the GL30 class.

The advantage is, that it is possible to create backwards compatible software by only importing certain classes. e.g. if you want to make something OpenGL 3.3 compatible, you just don't import anything above GL33. The disadvantage is, that you have to either remember all the version numbers and their features, or you look it up in the Khronos Specification, or just guess.

To use LWJGL functions, you can either:

- Import the class statically using e.g. import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30.*;
- Use the classname e.g. int vao = GL30.glGenVertexArrays();

Note that when pressing [Ctrl]+[Shift]+O all static import ending with * are resolved to indiviual imports.